# Trying to access Flash movie from JS works in FF, but not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript

I am setting up a Flash based MP3 player control (The standalone version of [WordPress Standalone Player](http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone)). I have a situation of multiple windows with players open. One window opens the other, so I have the `window.opener` property available.

When the child window is opened, I want to programmatically mute the audio player in the parent window.

**This works in Firefox, but not in IE 7 and 8.** I know little about Flash/Javascript interaction and I'm stuck. I am not getting any error messages.

To do this, the player SWF object has a setVolume() and close() function. These functions are not defined anywhere in Javascript so I guess that those are provided by the Flash object. This is supported by the following lines I found in the [Flash source code](http://tools.assembla.com/1pixelout/browser/audio-player/trunk/source/classes/Application.as) of the player:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) {
 ExternalInterface.addCallback("load", Application, Application.ei_loadFile);
 ExternalInterface.addCallback("close", Application, Application.ei_closePlayer);
 ExternalInterface.addCallback("open", Application, Application.ei_openPlayer);
 ExternalInterface.addCallback("setVolume", Application, Application.ei_setVolume);
```

In Firefox, this works:

```
if (typeof(AudioPlayer) != "undefined") 
var player = AudioPlayer.getPlayer("audioplayer_1");  // This shows up as 
                                                      // the player SWF object 
                                                      // in Firebug

if (player)
 if (typeof(player.setVolume) == "function")
  player.close();  // This works in FF but not in IE
```

but in IE, it doesn't. Is this because the callback is not available in IE? Or is there anything I need to do in addition?

Comment: Does player get a value in IE? Why are you testing for setVolume then calling close? Stick some alerts in your code and report back.

Comment: Will do, already on it. -------

Comment: All right folks, it was actually, and bizarrely, my function test. (The discrepancy between setVolume and close was an accident and had nothing to do with it.) I tested for the availablility of my `mutePlayer()` function like this: `if (typeof window.opener.mutePlayer == "function")` this doesn't work in IE, I don't know why. Probably because the functions are organized somewhere below the `window` object. If I remove that check, I can call the function and everything works fine. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it works in FF but not IE, then the issue is likely in the JavaScript code. ExternalInterface is pretty reliable (99% of the failures I encounter are a result of JavaScript issues, not ActionScript issues). Is window.opener supported in IE? Have you tested your JavaScript in a page without the Flash stuff to make sure the code works?

edit: how do I post this as a comment and not an answer??

edit edit: nvm, I am not cool enough yet to comment.

Comment: Cheers, check my comment above about what it was.